# PouchDB Adapter is missing

Tags: pouchdb

When I start

```
$ gulp watch
```

PouchDB is created successfully in Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit)

```
console.log(PouchDB.version);
console.log(lodash.keys(PouchDB.adapters));
new PouchDB('myname', {
  'adapter': 'idb', 
  'revs_limit': 1,
  'auto_compaction': true
});
```

and it outputs:

```
5.3.2
["http", "https", "idb", "websql"]
```

When I reload page (Cmd+R) I get error Adapter is missing:

```
5.3.2
["http", "https", "websql"]

Error: Adapter is missing 
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:5062:19 
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:5076:6 
at new PouchDB (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:5026:17) 
at openDb (http://localhost:9000/main/services/local-db-pouch-serv.js:313:14) 
at service.open (http://localhost:9000/main/services/local-db-pouch-serv.js:48:21) 
at service.open (http://localhost:9000/main/services/local-db-serv.js:26:23) 
at Object.localDbResolve (http://localhost:9000/main/main.js:104:22) 
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4535:17) 
at proceed (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:474:42) 
at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:470:26)
```

Is it a bug or do I smth wrong?